# Calling a function using switch-JAVA(homework)

Tags: java, function, matrix, switch-statement

I'm trying to solve this question:

Write a program that contains the following:

(i) A function to read an NΧM matrix.

(ii) A function to display the NXM matrix on the screen.

(iii) A function to add these two matrices.

(iv) A function to subtract these two matrices.

The program must also contain a main() function that will first declare two 3x3 matrices
A and B, allow input of data for A and B (using the function in (i)), and should
continuously display a menu as follows:

1. Add the matrices

2. Subtract the matrices

3. Exit

Please enter your choice(1-3) :
 
Upon selection of 1 or 2, the program should display the corresponding
result. When
 2 is selected, the program should exit.

I've tried to do it but i'm having a problem with the switch statement. The function call is underlined and i can't understand why.

There is an error message: The method add(int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int) in the type Number12 is not applicable for the arguments ()

Here's the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Number12 {

public static void read()
{
    int a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9;
    int b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("You will now enter the values for matrix A.");
    System.out.print("Enter the values for a1 a2 and a3: ");
    a1 = input.nextInt();
    a2 = input.nextInt();
    a3 = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter the values for a4 a5 and a6: ");
    a4 = input.nextInt();
    a5 = input.nextInt();
    a6 = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter the values for a7 a8 and a9: ");
    a7 = input.nextInt();
    a8 = input.nextInt();
    a9 = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("You will now enter the values for matrix B.");
    System.out.print("Enter the values for b1 b2 and b3: ");
    b1 = input.nextInt();
    b2 = input.nextInt();
    b3 = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter the values for b4 b5 and b6: ");
    b4 = input.nextInt();
    b5 = input.nextInt();
    b6 = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter the values for b7 b8 and b9: ");
    b7 = input.nextInt();
    b8 = input.nextInt();
    b9 = input.nextInt();

    add(a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9);
    subtract(a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9);
}

public static void add(int a1,int a2,int a3,int a4,int a5,int a6,int a7,int a8,int a9,int b1, int b2,int b3,int b4,int b5,int b6,int b7,int b8,int b9)
{
    int x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9;
    x1 = a1 + b2;
    x2 = a2 + b2;
    x3 = a3 + b3;
    x4 = a4 + b4;
    x5 = a5 + b5;
    x6 = a6 + b6;
    x7 = a7 + b7;
    x8 = a8 + b8;
    x9 = a9 + b9;

    System.out.println("The result is: ");
    System.out.println(x1+" "+x2+" "+x3);
    System.out.println(x4+" "+x5+" "+x6);
    System.out.print(x7+" "+x8+" "+x9);
}

public static void subtract(int a1,int a2,int a3,int a4,int a5,int a6,int a7,int a8,int a9,int b1, int b2,int b3,int b4,int b5,int b6,int b7,int b8,int b9)
{
    int x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9;
    x1 = a1 - b2;
    x2 = a2 - b2;
    x3 = a3 - b3;
    x4 = a4 - b4;
    x5 = a5 - b5;
    x6 = a6 - b6;
    x7 = a7 - b7;
    x8 = a8 - b8;
    x9 = a9 - b9;

    System.out.println("The result is: ");
    System.out.println(x1+" "+x2+" "+x3);
    System.out.println(x4+" "+x5+" "+x6);
    System.out.print(x7+" "+x8+" "+x9);
}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    int choice;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("You are asked to enter values for two 3x3 matrix. Below is the format: ");
    System.out.println("a1 a2 a3");
    System.out.println("a4 a5 a6");
    System.out.println("a7 a8 a9");
    System.out.println("and");
    System.out.println("b1 b2 b3");
    System.out.println("b4 b5 b6");
    System.out.println("b7 b8 b9");

    read();

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("****************************************************");
    System.out.println("****\t\t1. Add the matrices\t\t****");
    System.out.println("****\t\t2. Subtract the matrices\t****");
    System.out.println("****\t\t3. Exit\t\t\t\t****");
    System.out.println("****************************************************");
    System.out.print("Please enter 1-3 for your choice.");
    choice = input.nextInt();

    switch(choice)
    {
    case 1:
    {
        add();
        break;
    }
    case 2:
    {
        subtract();
        break;
    }
    case 3:
    {
        break;
    }
    default:
    {
        System.out.print("Please enter a number from 1-3.");
    }
    }

}
}
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: what IDE are you using ? eclipse ? what does you ide tell when moving moouse on underlined statement ? Are they warnings, error at compilation ?

Comment: Thats the error message: The method add(int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int) in the type Number12 is not applicable for the arguments ()

Comment: Your `switch` is just wrong, only 1 pair of `{ }` at the begunning and end of your `switch`

Comment: there is no add() method in your class, only a method add(int a1,int a2,int a3,int a4,int a5,int a6,int a7,int a8,int a9,int b1, int b2,int b3,int b4,int b5,int b6,int b7,int b8,int b9)

Comment: @philippelhardy you should and your comment as an answer

Comment: oh lord.. Have you guys covered arrays yet?

Comment: @christopher one step after the other; understanding static vs non-static first.

Comment: Method you want to call in case 1: is `read()`

Answer (score 0):

keep integer read within class instance by moving int you read into class members. Change static method add() read() and substract() to instance method (remove static word ).

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Number12 {

    int a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9;
    int b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9;

public void read()
{
```

remove add(...) and substract() calls from read.

then replace static add(a1...b9) with non static add()

In your main :

add line:

```
Number12 number = new Number12();
```

use **number.read()** instead **read()**

use **number.add()** instead **add()**

use **number.substract()** instead of **substract()**